# Modeling data in NoSQL MongoDB - whats better performance?

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling, nosql

I want to model data for searching music tracks based on few criterias,
let it be: criteria1, criteria2, criteria3.

I dont know whats better for querying performance, to store tracks in that schema:

```
criteria1, criteria2, criteria3
{
   _id: "_1512f23",
   name: "somevalue",
}


{
   _id: "_1512f23",
   name: "track 1",
   artist: "artist",
   criterias: {
          criteria1: "somevalue",
          criteria2: "somevalue",
          criteria3: "somevalue"
   }
}
```

or

```
criteria
{
   _id: "_1512f23",
   name: "somevalue",
   criterias: {
          track: "somevalue",
          track: "somevalue",
          track: "somevalue"
   }
}


{
   _id: "_1512f23",
   name: "track 1",
   artist: "artist",
}
```

What's better for searching?
Ofc there will be a lot of tracks and about 10-15 criteria documents in every criteria1,2,3 collection.

Comment: If the criteria are just tag-like bits of information them why not simply store the values in the track document and index them?  Do you need separate criteria documents?

Comment: @tom so u prefer first option?

Comment: I know its not the answer but it might help, Data modeling in MongoDB should be governed by your data access pattern. Its okay to get a chunk of data our from MongoDB and embed documents so that you can get the result in one go. Keeping that in mind, my suggestion would be to keep all the criteria with the track. IMHO.

Comment: What exactly do you store in the "criterias"? Please give an example. What do you add more often - new criterias or new tracks? When you add one, do you need to update many documents of the other?